Fullcalendar - Can i get hidden events?
I am stuck here and need some serious help. Basically I need to access events data which get hidden per day to render/display them as circles/some group of items at the bottom of day slot instead of displaying them in "more" popover. Is it possible without moreLinkClick? I want to display them on calendar load instead of accessing "hiddenSegs" data on moreLinkClick.
calendarOptions = {
//...calendar options
 dayMaxEvents: 2,
eventMaxStack: 2,
 initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
 moreLinkClick: (data) => {
  const desiredData = data.hiddenSegs // thats the data i wanna get without the need to click on moreLink
  return 'month';
},
}


Can you put some kind of mock code to look !!

Sure and sorry for not doing it earlier :( @Gopikrishna

No, this data is only available through that specific callback. At what other time would you want to access it, exactly?

At the time of calendar render/mount, I'd like to actually display these hidden events as dots/circles at the bottom of day cell

I don't think that's possible currently. You have the option to request features from the fullCalendar maintainers, but I suspect it wouldn't be a high priority. You could consider attempting to provide the code yourself - they also have some guidelines for providing contributions to the project.

Okay, thank you for your feedback and effort
